# List from Main Page to Appear on Division Page

Tags: list

I have a list located on the main portal landing page. I need to have that same list appear on the home page of the division page but when I go to add web parts it is not there to add.  How can I get that same list from the main portal landing page to appear on the division page?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Is the division a site collection of its own or is it even in a web application of its own?

Comment: they are both in the same site collection

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the top site where your list is and open SharePoint Designer.
2. Select List and Libraries.
3. Select the list you should display elsewhere.
4. Click inside the data area of the list.
5. Click the web part tab in the ribbon, and export the list to file.
6. Click Yes if you want that list data to be shown, even if other list within the site have the same name.
7. Open your division home page in the browser, where the list should be, and edit it.
8. Upload the web part file you saved earlier.
9. Select imported web parts, and add it to your page. Done

Reference: [SharePoint 2010 - Display list or library on another site (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SfpgoEUlIw)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the publishing features you can also use the Content Query Web Part to list the items from the top site. Then you will not get the list functionality of the list web part, but you will be able to display the items in a customized manner using xslt.